# Google Compute Engine (GCE) Startup Script // "apt-get upgrade" shutting down google script runner (google-startup-scripts.service)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, startupscript

Just in the past few days my GCE startup script has been failing when creating new  instances. I believe it is because the `apt-get upgrade` command is causing the google-startup-scripts service to shutdown or restart.  I added the `export` lines and `--force-conf` options to try and remedy the issue, but it still fails. If I remove the `apt-get upgrade` command from the script, everything completes successfully.  However, I then have to login to the server for a final "upgrade". Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

It may be worth noting that when I run `apt-get upgrade` manually, it asks me 2 prompts: 1) do I want to overwrite the sshserver config file (I don't), and 2) restart the following services (list below)

OS Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (e2-standard-2 compute engine)

**Startup Script Snippet**

```
apt-get -y update

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export NEEDRESTART_MODE=l
apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
```

**Log Snippet**

After unpacking the `google-guest-agent`, it appears to shutdown the script runner

```
google_metadata_script_runner startup-script-url: Preparing to unpack .../61-dbus-user-session_1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
google_metadata_script_runner startup-script-url: Unpacking dbus-user-session (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) over (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
google_metadata_script_runner startup-script-url: Preparing to unpack .../62-google-compute-engine-oslogin_20220714.00-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
google_metadata_script_runner startup-script-url: Unpacking google-compute-engine-oslogin (20220714.00-0ubuntu1~22.04.1) over (20210907.00-0ubuntu2) ...
google_metadata_script_runner startup-script-url: Preparing to unpack .../63-google-guest-agent_20220622.00-0ubuntu2~22.04.0_amd64.deb ...
systemd Stopping Google Compute Engine Shutdown Scripts...
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 1263 (startup-script-) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 1632 (apt-get) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 4500 (dpkg) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 4501 (sh) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 4502 (sh) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 4503 (dpkg-status) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 5377 (preinst) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 5382 (systemctl) remains running after unit stopped.
systemd Stopped Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
systemd google-startup-scripts.service: Consumed 25.932s CPU time.
```

**Services asked to restart after running "apt-get upgrade" manually**

```
[*] apache2.service                                           
[*] chrony.service                                            
[ ] dbus.service                                              
[*] fail2ban.service                                          
[ ] getty@tty1.service                                        
[*] google-cloud-ops-agent-diagnostics.service                
[*] google-cloud-ops-agent-fluent-bit.service                 
[*] google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service    
[*] google-osconfig-agent.service                             
[*] packagekit.service                                        
[*] polkit.service                                            
[*] postfix@-.service                                         
[*] serial-getty@ttyS0.service                                
[*] systemd-udevd.service                                     
[*] tomcat8.service                                           
[ ] unattended-upgrades.service                              
[ ] user@1354759638.service
```

Comment: I have tried your script, on the newly deployed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS e2-standard-2 machine type configuration. However the google-guest-agent_20220622.00-0ubuntu2~22.04.0_amd64.deb does not appear on the logs and the script successfuly restarted the services. I would suggest to contact GCP Support channel for further investigation on your Project

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Google was able to help. Apparently, I had an old template that referenced an older OS image (ARM instead of x86) which was incompatible with the instance. After updating to a new x86 instance, the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had an instance template that referenced an older OS image (ARM instead of x86) which was incompatible with the newly created instance. After updating to a new x86 OS image, the issue resolved itself.